# Elastic Beanstalk went to invalid state with t1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The Elastic Beanstalk environment is running on **t1.micro & db.t1.micro**, where we tried to update the **rds to db.m1.small** instance. This configuration change has been made on the Elastic Beanstalk and it is on **updating state for around 4 hours**, we thought AWS stuck somewhere internally. In this meantime, the AWS has not updated the Trace information. In order to retain the environment back (rollback of configuration update operation), we have **aborted the environment configuration update**. This has ended up on invalid state with the **health turned to grey**. This because AWS will not allow creating t1 environment nowadays, however, the rollback is trying to bring back the older t1 setup with an error-->                                                                                         RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following combination: DBInstanceClass=db.t1.micro, Engine=mysql, EngineVersion=5.6.37, LicenseModel=general-public-license. For supported combinations of instance class and database engine version.

> Any suggestion to bring back the environment to green would be really helpful.

Comment: Do you have snapshot of your DB?  You could deploy a new Env and restore that snapshot.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique : I have tried to create a new Elastic Beanstalk (db.m1) instance with the snapshot (db.t1). But however the environment is created and deployment failed with RDS timeout.                        Error -->[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out.  -------But the EC2 mysql command line could able to connect to the RDS.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right database connection string?  How are you getting the hostname, port, Etc of the provisioned Database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the source of the snapshot we could able to create a new EBS instance.  The only problem we faced during the snapshot to clone an instance is the application level configuration file change not done. BTW there is no proper root cause for the AWS DB upgrade failure from AWS.